# some terminal command doesn't release prompt and need ": q" to exit

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

i'm using `oh-my-zsh`  and terminal command on `VSCODE` or `iTerm` on macos machine.

some commands doesn't release or exit ( i have no idea how it's called sorry )

for example

`git status` print the status and i can input other command after it.
`git branch` print the branch but i have to do press control + C + ": q" to exit . few times ago it print the text and i can input other commands without ": q"

any one have an idea from where it can come or fix ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that `git status` works fine, but `git branch` *sometimes* doesn't, I'm going to guess that you've got your git pager set to something vi-like.

That is: the output from `git status` is usually pretty short, but the output from `git branch` takes more than one screenful, and needs scrolling.

What do the following commands show?

```
echo $PAGER
```

```
git config --get core.pager
```

For more about git paging, you could start here: https://medium.com/pragmatic-programmers/git-config-core-pager-807e17d64243

Comment: thanks for help

"> echo $PAGER" return "less" output

Comment: git config --global core.pager "cat".
this fix the problem. thanks it was making me crazy since months

Comment: how is this called so i can rename my issus properly to help other more easly please ?

Comment: Right, so if `PAGER=less` (which is a sensible default if you want paging), then you only need to press `q` to quit. The Ctrl+C and the colon should not be required. Your question is two-fold: "how do I disable paging for git output?" and (due to a misunderstanding about how less works); "how do I quit from less?"